# Substitute headers of fasta file in R

Tags: r

I have a fasta file of about 900 sequences:

```html
> fastafile<-read.fasta("example.fasta", seqtype="AA", as.string = TRUE, set.attributes = FALSE)
> head(fastafile)
$HHP62WH01AWFE1
[1] "TACGAGTATGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCGGCAATGGACGGAAGTCTGACCG"

$HHP62WH01A6F7R
[1] "TACTCTCGTGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTTAGTGGCAGATCATTTGCCTACTTGCACGCTACC"
```

I would like to substitute the headers of the file with a list (type character) of headers containing the sample Information and the read IDs:

```html
> head(sample)
[1] "sample1_HHP62WH01A0FTX" "sample2_HHP62WH01A1KAN"
```

So the new headers in`sample` are not the same order as the sequences in the `fastafile`. However, I wonder if there is a way to match the new headers with the corresponding fasta sequence while keeping the fasta format. 
I`d appreciate every help. Thank you!

Edit:

```html
> dput(head(fastafile))
structure(list(HHP62WH01AWFE1 = "TACGAGTATGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCGGCAATGGACGGAAGTCTGACCGAGCAACGCCGCGTGAGTGAAGAAG", 
    HHP62WH01A6F7R = "TACTCTCGTGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTTAGTGGCAGATCATTTGCCTACTTGCACGCTACCCTTGGTGTGCTCCTTCCGAATACT"), .Names = c("HHP62WH01AWFE1", 
"HHP62WH01A6F7R"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try `match`

```
names(fastafile) <- sample[match(names(fastafile), sub('.*_', '', sample))]
```

#### data

```
fastafile <- structure(list(sample1_HHP62WH01AWFE1 =
"TACGAGTATGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCGGCAATGGACGGAAGTCTGACCG", 
 sample3_HHP62WH01A6F7R = 
"TACTCTCGTGACTCCTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTTAGTGGCAGATCATTTGCCTACTTGCACGCTACC"), .Names =
c("sample1_HHP62WH01AWFE1", "sample3_HHP62WH01A6F7R"))

sample <- c( "sample1_HHP62WH01A0FTX", "sample1_HHP62WH01AWFE1", 
   "sample2_HHP62WH01A1KAN", "sample3_HHP62WH01A6F7R")
```

Comment: However, trying this I get just <NA> for the headers

Comment: @user3122796  I guess It is because those matching names are not in `sample` vector.  In the posted solution, I was matching the string after `_` in the sample with that of the names of the `fastafile`.